# Did the original Ethereum ICO have a different BIP32 word list?

Tags: ether, wallets, accounts

I have a 12 word seed which I believe should be BIP32 compliant and I think is from the original Ethereum ICO.

It was in an email sent to me (by myself) on 10th July 2014 - which was CoinSummit London where I first learned of Ethereum.

I suspect this is for the original Ethereum ICO, however none of the BIP32 compliant wallets I can provide this to (Ledger, Trezor, MetaMask) recognise the wordlist due to having words their dictionaries are missing such as:

- stop
- nerd
- stupid

I have investigated and learned there should be a wallet.json for this ICO which I cannot find - but thought these BIP32 memnonic should also resolve to an Ether key.

I wonder if someone has the wordlist for the original Ethereum ICO so I can see if this is a valid memnonic or not?